# Vuejs router forEach not fired

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I configured `VueJs` with `vue-router`, and everything is working fine. Except, I wanted to add a handler on the `beforEach` event of the router.

I tried already a lot and followed the documentation, but still I don't get it working. My code is:

**code:**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: routes,

});

router.beforeEach = function(to, from, next){
    console.log(to);
    if (to.path !== '/' && data.Registration.loggedIn === false) {
        console.log('not logged in');
        this.push('/');
    }
    console.log('logged in');

};

const flowApp = new Vue({
    el: '#vue_registration_app',
    router, data, methods
});
```

Even the `console.log(to)` doesn't do a thing.

Comment: Are you navigating through pages? This should work

Comment: yes, I navigated to other pages

Comment: Well, you can check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/samayo/xzjabL5p/ it works as you are doing it

Comment: actully check this, https://jsfiddle.net/samayo/xzjabL5p/1/ I added `next()` method which is missing in your example

Comment: Great!! Now at least something is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation it is suggested to use it like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // ...
})
```

Instead you are doing this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach = (to, from, next) => {
  // ...
})
```

So instead of the re-assignement of beforeEach, call the beforeEach function with your function as parameter and everything should work fine

Answer (score 0):

From [Vue-router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) "Make sure to always call the *next* function, otherwise the hook will never be resolved." – I think it should help.